# Is it an example of decorator pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, decorator

I've an example please tell me whether it is Decorator pattern or not?

```
public abstract class ComputerComponent  
{  
  String description ="Unknown Type";  
  public String getDescription()  
  {  
    return description;  
  }  
  public abstract double getCost();      
}  

public abstract class AccessoryDecorator  
{  
  ComputerComponent comp;  
  public abstract String getDescription();  
}  

public class PIIIConcreteComp extends ComputerComponent  
{  

  public PIIIConcreteComp()  
  {  

    description= "Pentium III";  
  }  
  public double getCost()  
  {  

    return 19950.00;    
  }  
}


  public class floppyConcreteDeco extends AccessoryDecorator  
  {  

    public floppyConcreteDeco(ComputerComponent comp)  
    { 
       this.comp=comp;  
    }  

  public String getDescription()  
  {  

    return comp.getDescription() +", floppy 1.44 mb";  
  }  

  public double getCost()  
  {  

    return 250+comp.getCost();  

  }  
}   
public class ComponentAssembly  
{  

  public static void createComponent()  
  {  

    ComputerComponent comp = new PIIConcreteComp();  

    // create a PIII computer object  

    ComputerComponent deco1= new floppyConcreteDeco(comp);  

    // decorate it with a floppy  

    //ComputerComponent deco2= newCDRomConcreteDeco(deco1);  

    ComputerComponent deco2= new floppyConcreteDeco(deco1);  

    // decorate with a CDRom or with one more floppy  

    System.out.println( deco2.getdescription() + " " + deco2.getCost());  

  }  
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please fix that mess. It's very hard to read that code the way you formatted it.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: I've modified it little bit now will you please tell me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your point is good, but your code wouldn't even compile, mainly because ComputerComponent has to be interface which has to be implemented by AccessoryDecorator and PIIIConcreteComp (and your braces are terribly messed, by the way). Usually AccessoryDecorator would also implement "default" implementation of it's methods like getDescription() {return comp.getDescription()}.

Comment: @ calavera.info: I've fixed the mess of bracets. Now you please check. I've one more doubt to ask whether 'AbstratDecoraor' class should extend component class or it should contain one of the members as 'component' as the 'component' is being decorated and if at all we want to decorate a component with 2 or more decorators how can it be possible in this case?

Is there seperate hierarchy of decorators or they extend component?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it seems to me that you don't understand the concept of interfaces. As I said in my answer - ComputerComponent should be an interface (not class) and you don't EXTEND interface but IMPLEMENT it. Also, once this interface is IMPLEMENTED by AccessoryDecorator and your "concrete" decorators EXTENDS that abstract class, then they implicitly IMPLEMENTS that interace too. If you don't understand this, you should be learning some more basic things about OOP and not design patterns, because it assumes perfect knowledge of such basics.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed the Decorator design pattern, albeit a bit of a messy example.

Answer (score 1):

It is a decorator pattern, but as Finbarr noted, it's a bit messy:

`floppyConcreteDeco` (which should be named starting with a capital letter) and/or `AccessoryDecorator` should extend `ComputerComponent`, however.

The reason is that the you'll want to use the decorator object the same way you use a "normal" `ComputerComponent` and you can't really do that unless you have a common base class or a common interface.